# JQuery check for element visibility in jest tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to check in the unit test that an element visibility state has been changed. I'm using `.is(":visible")` to do that and in unit test it always reports that the element is hidden but it works fine in browsers.

The code is as simple as this (see fully working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/romanko/v8g4oqye/1/)):

### html

```
<form>
      <div id="field">hi</div>
      <input type='checkbox' id="toggle">toggle</input>
      <input type='checkbox' id="show">show</input>
      <input type='checkbox' id="hide">hide</input>
</form>
```

### javascript

```
$('form').on('change', 'input#toggle[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  target_row = $('#field');

  if (target_row.length) {
    target_row.toggle("fast");
  }
});
```

As I wrote this works fine in browsers but does not work in the following test:

```
jest.dontMock('jquery');
jest.dontMock('../toggle.js');

$ = jQuery = require('jquery');

describe('toggle.js', function() {
  var sut = require('../toggle.js');
  function givenFields(formFields) {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = `
      <html><body><form>
      <div id="field">hi</div>
      ${formFields}
      </form></body></html>
    `;
    sut.initialize();
  }

  it('toggles the field', function() {
    givenFields(`<input type='checkbox' id="toggle">toggle</input>`);

    var initiallyVisible = $("#field").is(":visible");

    $('#toggle').click();

    // Checking that this is not jsdom rendering issue
    expect(document.hidden).toEqual(false);

    expect($("#field").is(":visible")).toEqual(!initiallyVisible);
  });

  it('shows the field', function() {
    givenFields(`<input type='checkbox' id="show">show</input>`);

    $('#show').click();

    expect($("#field").is(":visible")).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

The result is:

```
  ● toggle.js › toggles the field

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      26 |     expect(document.hidden).toEqual(false);
      27 |
    > 28 |     expect($("#field").is(":visible")).toEqual(!initiallyVisible);
         |                                        ^
      29 |   });
      30 |
      31 |   it('shows the field', function() {

      at Object.toEqual (src/__test__/toggle.spec.js:28:40)

  ● toggle.js › shows the field

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      34 |     $('#show').click();
      35 |
    > 36 |     expect($("#field").is(":visible")).toEqual(true);
         |                                        ^
      37 |   });
      38 | });
      39 |

      at Object.toEqual (src/__test__/toggle.spec.js:36:40)
```

`package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "toggle",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "3.2.0",
    "jest-cli": "24.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

Any ideas what may be wrong and how can I approach this problem?

One option that I don't like much as it is not a solution but a workaround is that I can check interactions with DOM instead of its state. By this I mean that I can verify calls to functions `toggle`, `show` and `hide`. This approach has a downside namely it increases the complexity as this would require me to maintain the state of DOM elements in tests and to introduce assumptions about the initial state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the first issue is that with a duration (in this case 'fast'), the [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and show functions don't just change the visibility:

> When a duration, a plain object, or a single "complete" function is provided, .toggle() becomes an animation method. The .toggle() method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously. When these properties reach 0 after a hiding animation, the display style property is set to none to ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

So you actually want to be checking for the `display` of the element.

The next issue is that it takes 200ms before jquery sets the display to `none`, so we need to account for that, meaning we could write something like this:

```
  it('toggles the field', function(done) {
    givenFields(`
      <div id="field">kuku</div>
      <input type='checkbox' id="toggle">toggle</input>
    `);

    var initialDisplay = $("#field").css('display');

    $('#toggle').click();

    // Checking that this is not jsdom rendering issue
    expect(document.hidden).toEqual(false);
    var expectedDisplay = initialDisplay === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block'
    setTimeout(function() {
      expect($("#field").css('display')).toEqual(expectedDisplay);
      done()
    }, 200)
  });
```

There might also be a way to inject [jest timer-mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) into jquery so that you can avoid the 200ms wait. Would be cool but not sure if it's possible.

EDIT:
[jQuery.fx.off = true;](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/)
This works great, leaving us with:

```
jest.dontMock('jquery');
jest.dontMock('./toggle.js');

$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
jQuery.fx.off = true;

describe('toggle.js', function() {
  var sut = require('./toggle.js');
  function givenFields(formFields) {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = `
      <html><body><form>${formFields}</form></body></html>
    `;
    sut.initialize();
  }

  it('toggles the field', function() {
    givenFields(`
      <div id="field">kuku</div>
      <input type='checkbox' id="toggle">toggle</input>
    `);

    var initialDisplay = $("#field").css('display');

    $('#toggle').click();

    // Checking that this is not jsdom rendering issue
    expect(document.hidden).toEqual(false);
    var expectedDisplay = initialDisplay === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block'
    expect($("#field").css('display')).toEqual(expectedDisplay);
  });

  it('shows the field', function() {
    givenFields(`
      <div id="field">kuku</div>
      <input type='checkbox' id="show">show</input>
    `);

    $('#show').click();

    expect($("#field").is(":visible")).toEqual(true);
  });

});
```

Comment: `jQuery.fx.off = true;` is very useful for keeping tests clean.